# long and int equality, what goes on with Equals()

Tags: c#

I encountered this today,  I am sure there is an excellent reason but why is
is the case for num2 equal to num1 inconsistent?

```
long num1 = 1;
int num2 = 1;

num1.Equals(num2);  // TRUE - cool.
num2.Equals(num1); // FALSE - hmm?
num2 == num1; // TRUE - ?! Whit?
```

Why is this.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/584128/What-is-the-difference-between-equalsequals-and

Comment: @Daniel: Not quite. This question here is about confusion of implicit widening conversions.

Answer (score 14):

```
num1.Equals(num2);
```

resolves to the overload of `long.Equals(long)` since there is an implicit widening conversion from `int` to `long`.

```
num2.Equals(num1);
```

calls `int.Equals(object)` which causes the `long` num1 to be boxed. Since this is not an `int`, the comparison returns false.

```
num2 == num1;
```

calls the overloaded `==` operator for `long` which again causes `num2` to be promoted to a `long` before being compared.

Comment: Yes absolutely, for value type it's not only sufficient to have similar value but types also must be same (or) should be implicit casted.

Comment: @Rahul It has nothing to do with whether it's a value or reference type.  Pretty much all (good) implementations of equality are defined to only return true for objects of the same type.  To not do so is typically a bug in the implementation of `Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

```
long num1 = 1;
int num2 = 1;

MessageBox.Show(num1.Equals(num2).ToString()); 
MessageBox.Show(num2.Equals((int)num1).ToString());
MessageBox.Show((num2 == num1).ToString());
```

It's a matter of explicitly casting the long as an int to make them equal as expected. The other ones are doing the casting for you.